# Advanced Custom Fields and Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, advanced-custom-fields

I created custom post types and fields using Custom Post Types UI and Advanced Custom Fields plugin on my wordpress site.

My goal is to create a Gravity Form on the front end of my site which populates a custom post type.

I installed this ACF plugin for Gravity Forms: 
https://github.com/stormuk/Gravity-Forms-ACF-Field/

I attempted to link the custom fields I created w/ ACF to the Gravity Form by choosing Post Fields --> Custom Field in the form creation menu.

However, I am not seeing the custom field names that I created in ACF as options in the 'Existing' custom fields drop down selector. Instead, I see options like 'field_512512a14d', which doesn't match the custom field name I defined. Even if I select these strange field names, completing the Gravity Form does not populate a new post on the backend.

Can someone please advise on how to get this plugin to function correctly?

Comment: you should look into field keys... [link](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/functions/update_field/#finding-the field key)

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that I have to create at least one entry manually into the custom post type before ACF fields will appear in Gravity's existing fields dropdown menu.

Answer (score 0):

I personally find it easier to just create the custom post types + custom fields in the functions.php file, and the link the form submission to the creation of the new custom post type.

I've written a post detailing the entire process here:
https://bay-a.co.uk/wordpress-tips/gravity-forms-custom-post-from-form/

Let me know if thats useful and/or if you don't understand any of the assumptions/prior stages.

Thanks,
Lloyd